# How do I create a function in R that returns the percentage of each number in a table and skips any 0 number

Tags: python, r, statistics

I need to create a function in a table using R that returns moving in an horizontal order and it doesn't calculate any 0 number. for example see this table below:

```
1  3 11
0  1  1
2  1  4
0  1  5
0  1  4
```

the first number will be calculated as **1/15*100 = 7%,** then the next will be **2/7*100 = 29%** then the next will be **3/15*100**... 0 numbers will be skipped.

Comment: 1 is the first number, 15 is the addition of 1+3+11. I'm simply trying to get the percentage  of each number based on the addition of each rows. I tagged it python because I believe anyone who knows python and sees this question might also know R and be able to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the dataframe with the rowwise sum.

```
res <- df/rowSums(df) * 100
res
#         V1       V2       V3
#1  6.666667 20.00000 73.33333
#2  0.000000 50.00000 50.00000
#3 28.571429 14.28571 57.14286
#4  0.000000 16.66667 83.33333
#5  0.000000 20.00000 80.00000
```

To ignore 0 values you may want to turn them to `NA`.

```
res[res == 0] <- NA
res
```

Answer (score 0):

We can using `proportions` along `margin = 1`, e.g.,

```
> proportions(as.matrix(df), 1)
             V1        V2        V3
[1,] 0.06666667 0.2000000 0.7333333
[2,] 0.00000000 0.5000000 0.5000000
[3,] 0.28571429 0.1428571 0.5714286
[4,] 0.00000000 0.1666667 0.8333333
[5,] 0.00000000 0.2000000 0.8000000
```

## Data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L), V2 = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), V3 = c(11L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `apply` in `base R`

```
100 *df/apply(df, 1, sum)
         V1       V2       V3
1  6.666667 20.00000 73.33333
2  0.000000 50.00000 50.00000
3 28.571429 14.28571 57.14286
4  0.000000 16.66667 83.33333
5  0.000000 20.00000 80.00000
```